# Using await with jsmediatags

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Is it possible to use Async await with jsmediatags to get id3 tags?

Can't seem to get it working, the current response type is painful,

{onSuccess:..., onError:...}

I need something like,

`let tags = await jsmediatags.read(file);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to `await` something, then it must return a `Promise`.  In this case `jsmediatags.read` (at the moment), uses callbacks (`onSuccess` etc).

You can wrap a `Promise` around the callback if that makes sense for you:

```
function awaitableJsmediatags(filename) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    jsmediatags.read(filename, {
      onSuccess: function(tag) {
        resolve(tag);
      },
      onError: function(error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then you are able to `await`:

```
let tags = await awaitableJsmediatags.read(file);
```